# How to open link in new tab on IE using selenium webdriver sampler in jmeter?

Tags: selenium, jmeter

My below code is working for chrome but when I tried to open link in new tab on IE browser using action class its not working.

I tried it in multiple way but I am getting following error.

Code:

```
Actions newTab= new Actions(WDS.browser);
newTab.contextClick(ele).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Error:

```
inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import java.io.FileWriter; import java.text.SimpleDateForma . . . '' : 

Error in method invocation: Method sendKeys( org.openqa.selenium.Keys ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions' : at Line: 45 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import java.io.FileWriter; import java.text.SimpleDateForma . . . '' : .sendKeys ( Keys .ARROW_DOWN )
```

I have also import org.openqa.selenium.Keys in my code

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use Beanshell for scripting**, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the reasons are in:

- Groovy supports all Java modern language features while in Beanshell you're stuck at [Java 5 level](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/grid/java-5-features-083037.html) (it means no generics, no diamond operators, no multi catches, no lambdas, etc.)
- Groovy provides [a lot of enhancements on top of Java SDK](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html)
- [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

So my expectation is that your code will start working once you choose `groovy` in the WebDriver's Sampler "Language" drop-down

[image]